# Downloading data using ASIHttpRequest

Tags: asihttprequest

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedImages"];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/savedImage1.jpg"];
NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingString:imageName];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/pictures/sample
```

.jpg"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

```
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringPath]]; //use the path from earlier
[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
[request setCompletionBlock:^
{
      NSData * dataFromrequest = [request responseData];
     NSLog(@"request  data  = %@",dataFromrequest);
     dataFromrequest writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

}];

I am using this code to download image from url. But I am using another url instead of "http://example.com/pictures/sample.jpg", valid one . when i try this code ..it doesn't go to the completion block. Please tell me what is the problem and what i am doing wrong.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good, for completion block we don't want to use the delegate. Please follow the code and you will get this.

ASIHTTPRequest *photoRequest =[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"http://example.com/pictures/sample.jpg")]];

[photoRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sample.png", stringPath]];

[photoRequest setCompletionBlock:^{

```
   NSLog(@"Response %d", [photoRequest responseStatusCode]);
```

}];

[photoRequest startAsynchronous];

Hope the you understand the code.